# Why do bots visit my website even though it hasn't been shared with anyone yet?

Tags: privacy, botnet

Is this usual? These bots hit my website every 15 minutes and they're the only visitors I get since I haven't shared the website with anyone yet... How do they even know about my website?

What is the purpose of this, are they trying to scrape info off of my page or something? Is this a privacy issue?

Comment: Welcome to the Internet. There are bots scanning every IP on the Internet looking for hits. Research shows that the average IP is a hit every 40 seconds. They can have a multitude of purposes.

Comment: Whether or not it is a privacy issue is entirely up to what's on your site. We can't answer that for you without a lot more context.

Comment: @schroeder just as an aside, is there any information on how much energy is being consumed by bots scanning IPs like this?

Comment: If you want to prevent your site from being accessed by bots (or humans) until you are ready to make it public, you might want to consider password-protecting the site.  This is simple to do using a .htaccess file to setup basic http authentication.

Comment: @Dunois yes, I've seen various studies on the environmental estimates over the years

Comment: Define "your website". Entire IPv4 address space is scanned constantly. If your website would use name based virtualization, a simple HTTP-request to IP-address wouldn't count as an access, unless they would know your website's hostname.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do bots visit my website even though it hasn't been shared with anyone yet?

Various reasons, mainly to scan and index the internet (companies like google, bing, yahoo, etc) and to find vulnerabilities to hack your website and use your servers for their own purposes.

> Is this usual?

Yes.

> How do they even know about my website?

There are many ways they can learn about your website, one of the more common is they watch new domains as they are registered and scan each as they come online.

> What is the purpose of this, are they trying to scrape info off of my page or something?

Information and hacking mostly as described earlier.

> Is this a privacy issue?

That depends on what you have on your website.  Anything you put on the internet shouldn't be considered private anymore.  Most websites that curate private information (social media, banks, email) create logins to keep the scanners from gaining access to items that would create a privacy issue for your users.